# Server.CreateObject Failed in Classic ASP IIS 10

Tags: iis, .net, asp-classic, windows-10

I installed our web application on a new **Windows 10** machine, which uses **IIS 10**.

Our app is 32-bit so I set the app pool to use 32-bit and I also set the web app folder to allow "EVERYONE" full control.

The create object is failing on a DLL we wrote and is in the web app. I have read in other places that the DLL needs to be registered, but I've also been told that only applies to COM+ not .NET DLL's.

The full error message:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/ERPORTALDASHBOARD/ERPORTALAPP/global.asa, line 443

800401f3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using classic ASP, so no .NET!. Classic ASP `Server.CreateObject` uses COM objects.

You may have written an assembly in .NET but to be used from classic ASP you still have to register it:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe pathToYourDLL
```

BTW: Don't give 'Everyone' full control to the files in your web site.